# Add header and expier mCache-Control time mdeflate on JS CSS and Images using AWS S3 php client

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, compression

AWS S3 php client  failed to add Cache-Control and Compressing resources with gzip or deflate  to Object.

**Info1:** `EC2 as hosting and select Ubuntu 14 as OS and install Apache PHP and i have check that it php and http works`.

**Info2:** `Rds as mysql database instance. it is working`

**Info3:** `I am  using s3 clodefont  for image css js front cdn`

**Issue:**`try to upload images css js and fonts file from below using php aws  s3 client`.

I have using this code but is not working:

```
            $client = S3Client::factory(array(
             'key'    => 'xxxxxxxx',
            'secret' => 'xxxxx',
            ));
             
             $bucket='mybucket';
             
             $result = $client->putObject(array(
                'Bucket'     => $bucket,
                'Key'        => $destinationpath,
                'Cache-Control' => 'max-age=86400',
                'Expires' => date('D, d M Y H:i:s T', strtotime('+24 hours')),
                'ACL'        => 'public-read',
                'Content-Encoding' => 'gzip',
                'SourceFile' => $sourcenpath,
              ));
```

The above code is `not set  compressing   and Content-Encoding and Expires date`

I need this thing for speedup

**Want:** `Gzip compression or deflate,   header Cache-Controla and Expires` to set `to new upload object of S3`

**Can any one help me?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `CacheControl` & `ContentEncoding` (without dashes).

See the AWS PHP SDK [putObject documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.S3.S3Client.html#_putObject) for more details.